# Finding $\sum\limits_{\substack{p<n\\p\text{ is prime}}}p^{n}\pmod{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose $n=2^{a}5^{b}$, where $a\geq 2$. We wish to find

$$S_{n}=\sum_{\substack{p<n\\p\text{ is prime}}}p^{n}\pmod{n}.$$

To do this, we find $S_{n}\pmod{2^{a}}$ and $S_{n}\pmod{5^{b}}$.

Since $\phi(2^{a})=2^{a-1}$, if $p\neq 2$, then $\gcd(p,2^{a})=1$, so

$$p^{n}=p^{2^{a}5^{b}}=\left(p^{2^{a-1}}\right)^{2\cdot5^{b}}\equiv1\pmod{2^{a}}.$$

If $p=2$, then $p^{n}\equiv0\pmod{2^{a}}$, and thus $S_{n}\equiv\pi(n)-1\pmod{2^{a}}$.

Now, we note that $\phi(5^{b})=4\cdot5^{b-1}$, so if $p\neq 5$, then $\gcd(p,5^{b})=1$, and

$$p^{n}=p^{2^{a}5^{b}}=\left(p^{4\cdot5^{b-1}}\right)^{2^{a-2}\cdot5}\equiv1\pmod{5^{b}}$$

since $a\geq 2$. And if $p=5$, we have $p^{n}\equiv0\pmod{5^{b}}$, so again we have $S_{n}\equiv\pi(n)-1\pmod{5^{b}}$, and thus

$$S_{n}\equiv\pi(n)-1\pmod{n}.$$

I believe this "trick" works whenever $n$ satisfies $p\mid n\Rightarrow p-1\mid n$ for all primes $p$ (that is, $S_{n}\equiv\pi(n)-1\pmod{n}$).

What do we know about the behavior of $S_{n}$ for other $n$? Are there ways of computing $S_{n}$ for other $n$ as well (perhaps given things like the factorization of $n$, $\pi(n)$, etc.). How does it behave as $n\rightarrow\infty$? Maybe it has some asymptotic relationship with $\cfrac{n}{\ln n}$?

Answer (score 2):

> $n=2^a5^b,a\ge 1$.

For $p\nmid n$ then $ \phi(2^a)| n$ thus $p^n \equiv 1\bmod 2^a$ and $\phi(5^b)| 2n$ thus $p^{2n} \equiv 1\bmod 5^b$, since $\Bbb{Z/5^b Z}^\times$ is cyclic it means $p^n \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 5^b$.

The sign depends on if $a\ge 2$ and if $p$ is a square $\bmod 5^b$ or not ie. if $p$ is a square $\bmod 5$ or not. That is to say with $$f(l,n)=(l^n \bmod n)= l^n - n\lfloor l^n/n \rfloor$$ then $$ \gcd(l,n)= \gcd(l+5k,n)=1 \implies f(l,n)=f(l+5k,n)$$

$7$ is not a square $\bmod 5$ 
thus you are looking at $$\sum_{p<n}f(p,n)=f(2,n)+f(3,n)+f(5,n)+\frac{1+f(7,n)}{2}\sum_{5<p<n}1+\frac{1-f(7,n)}{2}\sum_{5<p<n} (\frac{p}{5})$$
By the PNT in arithmetic progression we get as $n\to \infty$ $$\sum_{p<n}f(p,n)\sim \frac{1+f(7,n)}{2}\frac{n}{\log n}$$
If $a\ge 2$ then $f(7,n)=1$, otherwise it is an integer $\in [\sqrt{n},n]$.